# UIButtons are not responding during animation - iOS Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uibutton

I'm building a calculator app, when I tap on the buttons there is a short animation. The problem is the buttons do not respond while they are animating, which makes the app feel laggy.

I found some solutions for Objective-C using:

```
UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
```

but nothing for Swift 3, my code looks like this:

```
func myButton () {

    sender.layer.backgroundColor = firstColor
    sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControlState.normal)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        sender.layer.backgroundColor = secondColor
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Call different method of UIView:

```
func myButton () {
    sender.layer.backgroundColor = firstColor
    sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControlState.normal)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,
                   delay: 0.0,
                   options: .allowUserInteraction,
                   animations: {
                       sender.layer.backgroundColor = secondColor },  
                   completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Sasha's answer is correct (voted.) To explain, by default the system disables user interaction during animations. By passing in the `.allowUserInteraction` option, you override that default. However, you still can't click on a button that's moving from one place to another at a point mid-flight. What really happens is that the view gets put in it's final position as soon as the animation begins, and the animation is done in a display-only "presentation layer" that's drawn on top. If you want to be able to tap on things that are moving you have to write custom code to do so.

Comment: @DuncanC How can we tap on things that are moving?

Comment: @YunusT., you can't, normally. You have to attach a tap gesture recognizer to the parent view and then hit test against the moving view's layer in the presentation layer. You should post another question about that if you want a detailed answer.